# Titanium Appcelerator FTP upload

Tags: sockets, ftp, titanium, appcelerator

```
var ftpConfig = {
host:'www.test.com',
port:21,
user:'uname',
password:'upwd'
};

var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'white'});

var connectButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title:'Connect',
top: 155,
left:30,
right:30,
height:40
});
win.add(connectButton);
var upB = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title:'upload',
top: 195,
left:30,
right:30,
height:40
});
win.add(upB);
upB.addEventListener('click', upload);
var controlSocket = Ti.Network.createTCPSocket({
hostName:ftpConfig.host,
port:ftpConfig.port,
stripTerminator:true,
mode:Titanium.Network.READ_WRITE_MODE
});

controlSocket.addEventListener('read', function(e) {
Titanium.API.info('[SERVER] ' + e.data);
Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(e.data));
responseCode = e.data.toString().substr(0,3);

switch (responseCode) {
    case '220': // server ready
        Titanium.API.info('[CLIENT] Logging in');
        controlSocket.write('USER ' + ftpConfig.user + '\n\r', e.from);     
        connectButton.title = 'Disconnect';
        break;

    case '221': // goodbye
        controlSocket.close();
        Titanium.API.info('Disconnected from ' + controlSocket.hostName);
        connectButton.title = 'Connect';
        break;

    case '230': // user logged in
        Titanium.API.info('[CLIENT] Successfully logged in');
        break;

    case '331': // password required
        Titanium.API.info('[CLIENT] Sending password');
        controlSocket.write('PASS ' + ftpConfig.password + '\n\r', e.from);
        break;

    case '530': // login incorrect
        controlSocket.close();
        Titanium.API.info('Login failed, disconnected from ' +        controlSocket.hostName);
        connectButton.title = 'Connect';
        break;

    default: 
        Titanium.API.info('Unhandled response: ' + responseCode);
        break;
}
});

controlSocket.addEventListener('readError', function(e) {
Titanium.API.info('Socket read error: ' + e.error);
});

controlSocket.addEventListener('writeError', function(e) {
Titanium.API.info('Socket write error: ' + e.error);
});


connectButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
if (connectButton.title == 'Connect') {
    try {
        Titanium.API.info('[CLIENT] Connecting to ' + controlSocket.hostName);
        controlSocket.connect();
    } catch (e) {
        Titanium.API.info('Error: ' + e.error);
    }                   
} else {
    if (controlSocket.isValid) {
        Titanium.API.info('[CLIENT] Quitting');
        controlSocket.write('QUIT\r\n');
    }
}   
});

function upload()
{
var fx = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'home_en.png');


controlSocket.write('STOR '+fx.name+'\r\n');
    controlSocket.write("PWD\n");

}
```

Hello !

I have some question about "sockets" and titanium.
I'm trying to upload a file on my server but when the file is upload i only get an empty file 0octet on the server. I've read a lot about this on stackoverflow but i can't solve my problem .

Answer (score 1):

Ftp protocol assumes a file upload success only when the socket is gracefully closed. To gracefully close a socket, there should not be any pending read or write when the socket is closed.

Comment: for the moment i get an error from server :
file to upload file:///Users/zuhn/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/5D7A9E41-FACF-44D6-8501-F33CD9D61242/Documents/home_en.png
[INFO] :   [SERVER] 425 Unable to build data connection: Invalid argument

I still don't anderstand sorry

Comment: Ok, 
After logged in i send this command to enter passive mode

    case '230': // user logged in
   Titanium.API.info('[CLIENT] Successfully       logged in');
   controlSocket.write("PASV\n");
   break;

same result on server 0octet file, but no more error, i have to finish the upload process ? what is the next step ?

Comment: Sniff the traffic with wireshark & check whether there is graceful connection close.